# The Odin Project Ruby on Rails Advanced Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm currently reading this:

http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms

to learn more about forms in rails. I'm at the section "Prepopulating select Tags with Collections". I'm a bit confused as to something in the reading. Under the small example where it creates a dropdown menu, it says that "Your create action will recieve an attribute called "user_id"."

Here's the code in question:

```
..
<select name="user_id">
  <%= @users.each do |user| %>
    <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
..
```

I can't see how the data from the dropdown menu is sent to the create action. If I were doing it with a form_for it would have a submit function that automatically sends the form contents in the params hash over to the create action. I'm pretty unclear as to how the create action is recieving the data from the form via the params hash if there isn't a form_for or a submit button of any kind. What exactly is mapping the form contents to the create action?

Comment: Notice the dots, it's not full code. This select tag will be used inside a form_for.

Comment: So the attribute that the select tag will fill is specified in <select name="user_id">? I.e. my params hash will have something akin to {"user_id" => "dropdown_menu_item_here"}?

Comment: @user3731368 Exactly! It's the name attribute which decides for which field that value would be and eventually how your params from your form will reach the controller method

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've been confused as to how exactly the params hash interacts with the select tag when used in a form_for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `..` above and below the given code are saying that this is only a code snippet - somewhere there will be a submit button.  When the form is submitted, the selected value will be sent to the controller as part of the params hash under the key `user_id` - that's happening in this line:

```
<select name="user_id">
```

you can try this for yourself:  if you change `user_id` in that line to `my_param_name`, your params hash will look something like this:

```
{'my_param_name' => 23}
```

where `23` is the `user_id` of the selected user from the list